# Powershell EnsureUser: "The specified user could not be found."

Tags: powershell, spuser

I was trying to get a user with EnsureUser to make sure that if the user doesn't exists on the site collection, it is added right away.

```
 Write-Host  "LoginName" $usernameau #this prints mydomain/username

         try {
           $userAuthor =  $spwebout.EnsureUser($usernameau) # getUserOut($usernameau)

        } catch   { 

        write-host $_.Exception 
        }
```

Unfortunately I get the following exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "EnsureUser" with "1" argument(s): "The specified user  could not be found." ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: T
he specified user  could not be found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureUser(String logonName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

What could be the problem? 
I am sure the user exists on AD.

**EDIT:**
I have to look better into it but I've found out is that the user that gives me the problem is not enabled in AD.

Comment: do you call it with or without domain name? ex:  testdomain\user ? or do you maybe even have claims authentification?

Comment: @Gwny I call it with the domain name

Comment: do you have claims?

Comment: yes I have claims. I mean I have claims enabled. Or you mean something else?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. Maybe it's stored with the whole claim login name. You can take a look at the Users List on the spweb object and try to get your loginname from there

Comment: according to my understanding with EnsureUser  the iser spweb shouldn't necessarily be on the spweb list. If it is not there , it should be added when you run the command. The users that give me the problems are not in the spweb by the way

Comment: have you tried ensuring it with de claims name?

Comment: I've tried with claims. It doesn't work with the spweb I need. In another spweb, which was old with claims worked. it seems  because the user got disabled , I'm looking into it

Comment: does your account running powershell get enough permission on the target site collection?

Comment: Yes., it does. I've used a primary site collection administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution in another thread...

```
$wApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://nacho.sharepoint.taco"
$wApp.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Clear()
```

In my case, my people picker must have defaulted to the domain I was testing in, not the domain I was try to add users from.  My Profile Store is configured to pull from two domain (Test and Prod).